# How to remove consecutive repeating characters from every line?

Tags: bash, text-processing

I have the below lines in a file

```
Acanthocephala;Palaeacanthocephala;Polymorphida;Polymorphidae;;Profilicollis;Profilicollis_altmani;
Acanthocephala;Eoacanthocephala;Neoechinorhynchida;Neoechinorhynchidae;;;;
Acanthocephala;;;;;;;
Acanthocephala;Palaeacanthocephala;Polymorphida;Polymorphidae;;Polymorphus;;
```

and I want to remove the repeating semi-colon characters from all lines to look like below (note- there are repeating semi-colons in the middle of some of the above lines too)

```
Acanthocephala;Palaeacanthocephala;Polymorphida;Polymorphidae;Profilicollis;Profilicollis_altmani;
Acanthocephala;Eoacanthocephala;Neoechinorhynchida;Neoechinorhynchidae;
Acanthocephala;
Acanthocephala;Palaeacanthocephala;Polymorphida;Polymorphidae;Polymorphus;
```

I would appreciate if someone could kindly share a bash one-liner to accomplish this.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. SO is a question and answer page for professional and enthusiastic programmers. Please add your own code to your question. You are expected to show at least the amount of research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Comment: See [How to remove duplicate characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/187052/117037) on [unix.se]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`tr`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/tr.html) with "squeeze":

```sh
tr -s ';' < infile
```

Answer (score 2):

```
perl -p -e 's/;+/;/g' myfile   # writes output to stdout
```

or

```
perl -p -i -e 's/;+/;/g' myfile   # does an in-place edit
```

Comment: The sed solution is practically the same: `sed 's/;\+/;/g' myfile`, with option `-i` to do in-place. Feel free to add that to your answer :)

Comment: @wjandrea Thanks. In all honesty, I don't particularly like sed's behaviour with `+` versus `\+`, because it is the exact opposite of how escaping is done in regexps in other apps (not just perl, but also e.g. python and egrep), where the backslash would mean to treat the `+` as a literal. (Obviously you could add the sed solution as a separate answer if you want.)

Comment: OK, I posted my own :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to edit the file itself:

```
printf "%s\n" 'g/;;/s/;\{2,\}/;/g' w | ed -s foo.txt
```

If you want to pipe a modified copy of the file to something else and leave the original unchanged:

```
sed 's/;\{2,\}/;/g' foo.txt | whatever
```

These replace runs of 2 or more semicolons with single ones.

Answer (score 0):

could be solved easily by substitutions. 
I add an awk solution by playing with the FS/OFS variable:

```
awk -F';+' -v OFS=';' '$1=$1' file
```

or

```
awk -F';+' -v OFS=';' '($1=$1)||1' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sed version of [alaniwi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62179064/4518341):

```
sed 's/;\+/;/g' myfile  # Write output to stdout
```

or

```
sed -i 's/;\+/;/g' myfile  # Edit the file in-place
```